# Помогите решить проблему, checkbox счетчик css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

```css
.poznavat input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
   counter-increment: list;
}
#resultat  {
   display: block;
}
.poznavat input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #resultat{
  display: block;
}
#resultat::after {
  content: "("counter(list)"/15)";
}
}
#resultat {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="poznavat">

<div class="channel">
    <div class="img">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="id_92" value=""> <span class="spanchik"> <img title="Футбол 2" data-id="1" alt="Футбол 2" src="images/futbol2.png" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;width:auto;"> </span> </label>
    </div>
    <h2 data-fontsize="14" data-lineheight="14">Футбол 2</h2>

</div>
<div id="resultat"> </div>
```

как сделать чтоб счетчик реагировал на чекбокс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С такой структурой на css не получиться сделать

Если изменить структуру

```css
#resultat {
  position: absolute;
}

#resultat::after {
  content: "("counter(list)"/15)";
}

.poznavat input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  counter-increment: list;
}

.poznavat input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#resultat {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="poznavat">

  <input type="checkbox" id="id_92" name="id_92" value="">
  <label for="id_92" class="spanchik"><img title="Футбол 2" data-id="1" alt="Футбол 2" src="images/futbol2.png" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;width:auto;"> </label>
  <h2 data-fontsize="14" data-lineheight="14">Футбол 2</h2>
  <div id="resultat"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а на JQuery возможно такое провернуть?

Comment: @Богдан такой вариант подойдет? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/L3vjab81/