# Вложенность тегов CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, checkbox

```
<div class="first">
    <input type="checkbox" class="second">
</div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Как записать на CSS, чтобы когда .second:checked (чекбокс был нажат) у .third фон менялся на красный?

Или может есть варианты без чекбокса?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите решить проблему, checkbox счетчик css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692787/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-checkbox-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-css)

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент, в CSS нет возможности обратиться к древу выше.
Можно вот так:

```css
.third{
  background: red;
}
.second:checked + .third{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="second">
<div class="third">Something</div>
```

Comment: Быть может? это можно сделать не на чекбоксах, а скажем при помощи ссылки? но без использования JS!

Comment: Ссылка не сохраняет состояния, которые можно менять как у чекбокса. Тем более что разницы нет - при такой верстке, сделать только на CSS запрошенного нельзя (от вложенного элемента нельзя достать до раннего).

Comment: Основная проблема в следующем: будет 4 чекбокса рядом(каждый свой цвет), и не хотелось бы каждый позиционировать отдельно, проще их закинуть в один блок и после разместить на странице, где мне удобно. Но боюсь что без JS здесь не обойтись... Спасибо за доп. информацию

Comment: Довольно обычное действие, обычно так табы верстают (без JS и на чекбоксах). Но либо надо верстать определённым образом, либо юзать JS. Можете в этот блок закинуть и то, что надо подсвечивать, тогда юзаем пример из моего ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант на JS, если элементы не в одном родительском узле...

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('input').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.third').style.background = 'red';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.third').style.background = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <input type="checkbox" class="second">
</div>
<div class="third">third</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но JS не подходит :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой способ. Минус - у `label` нет состояний, которые можно стилизовать.

```css
label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.collapsed{
  display:none;
}
.collapsed:checked + .target{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triggers">
  <label for="third"></label>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <input type="checkbox" id="third" class="collapsed">
  <div class="target">ASDASDASD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение....

Comment: @Air, вполне стандартное, просто недоделанное. Автор, чтобы у чекбокса появилось "состояние" поместите лэйбл сразу после него и на состоянии :checked меняйте ::before и ::after у лэйбла.

Comment: Прочтите внимательно вопрос. Инициатор(в данном случае label) и целевой элемент должны находиться в разных блоках.

Comment: @DaemonHK, стандартное или  не стандартное, но из трех ответов, больше всего соответствует требованиям автора.... Я не додумался...

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров вы это сами придумали или ТС просто не знает как сверстать правильно?

Comment: @DaemonHK "Основная проблема в следующем: будет 4 чекбокса рядом(каждый свой цвет), и не хотелось бы каждый позиционировать отдельно, проще их закинуть в один блок и после разместить на странице, где мне удобно." - это цитата из комментария ТС под первым ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, ок, проглядел видимо, но в любом случае то что хочет ТС и как он это хочет реализовать несовместимо.

Comment: @DaemonHK, согласен

Answer (score 1):

По идее ТС нужно пересмотреть свой подход к данному вопросу, но уж если хочется заморочиться с вложенностью, как сделал участник Геннадий Журов, то можно построить что-то подобное, но вложенность нарушить придется в любом случае, потому что мы лишимся либо "чекнутого инпута", либо закрашенного блока:

```css
label{
 display:inline-block;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 border:1px solid;
 border-radius:3px;
}
.content{
 margin-left:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.collapsed{
 display:none;
}
.collapsed:checked~label{
 background:green;
}
.collapsed:checked~label + .content>.target{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triggers">
  <input type="checkbox" id="third" class="collapsed">
  <label for="third">&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="target">ASDASDASD</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```